# Batching in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I have a few hundred images I need to batch process. Basically I need to apply a set of images to a single PSD using the Apply Image function, save as a new jpg with file numbering if possible, then do it all over again with the next image and same PSD.

I'm using the Apply Image function in Photoshop to apply one image to another. So I'm blending a set of jpegs one at a time to a semi-transparent PSD file.

The problem I am having when I want to run the batch, is that it's taking the same image to merge every time, and I'm also having issues saving as the original image file name.

Answer (score 0):

First make a copy of the image folder that contains the jpegs, and work on that copy to ensure you don't overwrite your original files.

Open your PSD in Photoshop - this is the source image that will be applied to the jpegs. It must be left open for the action to work.

Now begin recording a new action, and do the following steps:

1. open one of the jpegs* (from the copied image folder obviously)
2. Click Image > Apply image - in the dropdown select the PSD file as the source.
3. File > Save

Stop recording.

Close the jpeg, but leave the PSD open.

Now use the action you recorded using File > Automate > Batch.

Make sure you select the option which says "**Override Action Open Commands**", and that the source and destination folders are the same (both pointing to the copied image folder).

*Obviously, the jpeg you used in this step will already be applied - so you could take that out of the folder before running the batch on the rest of the images or it will get done twice.

Comment: im trying to apply the jpeg to the psd not the other way around. as the psd is the base and the jpeg is a texture in a way

Comment: Batch processing is for multiple files, not one file. So that's not gonna work! Perhaps you could use a script. I doubt an action could handle it.